# Kafka Consumer and Producer in the same IntelliJ project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I am going through a tutorial on Kafka, the author is using eclipse and has both the Kafka Consumer and the Kafka Producer both running in Eclipse. I use IntelliJ which I am new to, and I have to create two different projects one for the consumer and one for the Producer. How to run two different projects in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create two classes having main functions, one for producer and one for consumer and you can run both.

This is main signature you need:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}
```

Comment: can you run then both at the same time in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes you can, run and debug.

Comment: Thanks, Im still new but you guys were quick and accurate

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I asked this, so long that I ran into the same issue again and found this post, But I have an easier answer now. If you are using IntelliJ like me there isnt an Import menu item like Eclipse, so what you need to do is create you two spring boot projects.

Lets say ones a Kafka Producer and the other is a kafka Consumer, go to springboot create both projects, then unzip them both on your desktop. now create a new folder called "Kafka" move both your springboot projects into the new folder and open that folder in intelliJ, now you will have both your project running in IntelliJ.

This will work as long as each project has its own main method as stated above.

Comment: I didn't even think of importing one into the other good observation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can open two different projects using IntelliJ

1. File -> new -> Project
2. Enter your config
3. Then it will appear this window, And choose **New Window**

[image]

Comment: this is completely the opposite of what was asked, I wantked to know how to open two springboot projects int the same window. This is how lots of Eclipse tutorials are put together, its just that IntellliJ doesnt have the same import mene items